# imagemap in objective c

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i want to make something like this
http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/images/images_famsupp_220.html

and i want to know if there is class to do it in objective c?
thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if i understood you correctly, you want to have several sensitive points on an image view?

try adding

```
-(void) touchesBegan: (NSSet *) touches withEvent: (UIEvent *) event 
 {
       NSLog(@"Touches: %@", touches); //examine this!
 }
```

to your code.

it provides UITouch instances in the touches-set, each having an location point for your views.

checkout

```
  UITouch locationInView:;
```

regs.

Answer (score 0):

`UIWebView` supports image maps. If you want a pure Objective-C solution I would recommend using an `UIImageView` and capture touches where you would like to map the image. Once some one touches the view you can then call the appropriate action.